# before(:each) vs just before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am new to ruby on rails. And playing around with testing

Is there a difference between

```
before(:each) do 
  #some test code
end
```

and

```
before do
  #some test code
end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `before` method accepts a `scope` parameter that defaults to `:each`. When you leave it out, it's implied that you mean `:each`, so your two examples do the exact same thing.

Here is a helpful tidbit from the RSpec RDoc, [Module: RSpec::Core::Hooks#before](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Hooks%3abefore):

> Parameters:
>
> - scope (Symbol) — `:each`, `:all`, or `:suite` **(defaults to `:each`)**
> - conditions (Hash) — constrains this hook to examples matching these conditions e.g. `before(:each, :ui => true) { ... }` will only run with examples or groups declared with `:ui => true`.