# login_as works for first test only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write some system tests with RSpec but don't get the `login_as` doesn't work for the second test. It always fails because the user gets redirect to `/login`. Do I have to put the `let!` blocks elsewhere?

```rb
describe "Users" do
  describe "dashboard" do
    let!(:user_a) { create(:user, lastname: "Z") }
    let!(:user_b) { create(:user, lastname: "A") }

    before do
      login_as(user_a)

      puts "############"
      puts "# this one prints a different user for each test"
      puts user_a.to_json
      puts "############"

      visit "/users"
    end

    it "list users alphabetically" do # rubocop:disable RSpec/MultipleExpectations
      expect(find_all('a[class^="Table__Row"]')[0].find_all('div[class^="Table__Column"]')[1]).to have_content(user_b.firstname)
      expect(find_all('a[class^="Table__Row"]')[1].find_all('div[class^="Table__Column"]')[1]).to have_content(user_a.firstname)
    end

    it "list the right amount of users" do
      expect(find_all('a[class^="Table__Row"]').length).to eq(2)
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea what could be wrong? I've set `config.use_transactional_fixtures` to `true` in my `rails_helper.rb`.

Comment: [Not related to your question] I don't know how you have implemented your "user" factory, but I think you would prefere to use `have_content(user_b.lastname)` instead of `have_content(user_b.firstname)`.

Comment: [Related to your question] Did your tried to use `sign_in` instead of `login_as`? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877687/rspec-devise-login-as-does-not-work-on-the-first-test

Comment: Haha, no, in fact I check the firstname instead of lastname. I'm just overwriting the lastname to force the ordering of the list. `sign_in` doesn't work either :-(

Comment: Yes, but is your firstname random? Or is it the same for all users? (it depends on your implementation of the user's factory) If it's the case, your test won't test anything. I think the most logic thing to do is to compare the `lastname` in your case (since the order concerns the lastname, not the firstname). But it was just an opinion, nothing more. Concerning your issue, I have this code in one of my projects, don't know if it can help: `def login_as(user)`, `@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]`, `sign_in(user, scope: :user)`, `end`

Comment: The firstname is random and I want to ensure that the firstname is the one of the generated user. I have implemented the helpers from https://github.com/forem/forem and know everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using before(:all) instead will solve your problem. Before without an argument means before(:each), as seen in [before(:each) vs just before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584161/beforeeach-vs-just-before)

Comment: I can't use the factories inside `before(:all)`: let declaration `user_a` accessed in a `before(:context)` hook. `let` and `subject` declarations are not intended to be called
       in a `before(:context)` hook, as they exist to define state that
       is reset between each example, while `before(:context)` exists to
       define state that is shared across examples in an example group.

Comment: If you don't need access to the user inside the it blocks, simply declare them on the before block.

If you do need access, set it to a variable, like @user_a

Comment: How do I set it to a variable?

Comment: @user_a = create(:user, lastname: "Z")

Comment: Aaaah, I see/understand. Same principle like here: https://github.com/forem/forem/blob/5b62811c9874fa2770fe3f720abac1f80fe6279f/spec/system/dashboards/user_sorts_dashboard_articles_spec.rb#L37-L39